# Updating parameters for a Gaussian Mixture Model after each iteration using normalmixEM2comp in R Language

Tags: r

How the following function updates the parameters after each iteration for a Gaussian Mixture Model?

```
normalmixEM2comp(x, c(0.2,0.8), c(0,5), c(1,4), eps= 1e-8, maxit = 10, verb=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hello. Please read what is good question in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey, normalmixEM2comp is from mixtools? you can find the source code at https://rdrr.io/cran/mixtools/src/R/normalmixEM2comp.R . Maybe you can be more specific about which part you would like an explanation?

Comment: I was looking for the source code actually but was not able to. That's answer my question. Thank you very much.